# Rijndael S-box in C

Tags: c, cryptography

I am trying to write a function which computes the Rijndael S-box according to this Wikipedia article. [Rijndael S-box](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rijndael_S-box)

```
#define ROTL8(x,shift) ((uint8_t) ((x) << shift | ((x) >> (8 - (shift)))))
uint8_t sbox(uint8_t b)
{
    uint8_t s = b ^ ROTL8(b,1) ^ ROTL8(b,2) ^ ROTL8(b,3) ^ ROTL8(b,4) ^ 0x63;
    return s;
}
```

Now this works when I try sbox(0x00)=0x63 and sbox(0x01)=0x7c, but it starts to go astray from sbox(0x02), which should be 0x77, but I get 0x5d instead. I suspected the issue might be the rotation not working correctly, but that now does not seem like an issue...

What is wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the wrong way to implement AES's S-box - most implementations are either hardcoded (they explicitly write the entire S-box as a 256-byte array), or they **iteratively** build the entries of the S-box, as in the Wikipedia article you linked:

```
void initialize_aes_sbox(uint8_t sbox[256]) {
    uint8_t p = 1, q = 1;
    
    /* loop invariant: p * q == 1 in the Galois field */
    do {
        /* multiply p by 3 */
        p = p ^ (p << 1) ^ (p & 0x80 ? 0x1B : 0);

        /* divide q by 3 (equals multiplication by 0xf6) */
        q ^= q << 1;
        q ^= q << 2;
        q ^= q << 4;
        q ^= q & 0x80 ? 0x09 : 0;

        /* compute the affine transformation */
        uint8_t xformed = q ^ ROTL8(q, 1) ^ ROTL8(q, 2) ^ ROTL8(q, 3) ^ ROTL8(q, 4);

        sbox[p] = xformed ^ 0x63;
    } while (p != 1);

    /* 0 is a special case since it has no inverse */
    sbox[0] = 0x63;
}
```

notice that `xformed`'s value - which is the value you calculated in your own implementation - changes iteratively over the iterations (and it is not the S-box value of its `q` the way you implemented). In practice, every manual S-box construction has some sort of similar iterative process - [look over at Code Golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/3766/implement-rijndaels-s-box) for some creative implementations.

Comment: I've just followed the code with the debugger and realized that this given code had its 'p' variable value not incremented by 1, but somewhat "randonly" yet covering the entire index range from 0 to 255. I am guessing it rather more practical just to have an array of precomputed table?

Comment: Yes, it's more practical :) - it's how openssl seems to do it: https://github.com/openssl/openssl/blob/master/crypto/aes/aes_core.c#L1814